# Direct USB type C connection preventing SD card reader from being recognized

Tags: usb, usb-storage, usb-c, micro-sd-card, usb-2

I have a micro SD card I want to read on my M2 MacBook Pro (Ventura).

I recently bought an adapter, that in theory is supposed to read said card.

On the manual the reader is described as a “T-Flash (Micro SD HD/XC) Card Reader (USB2.0)”, [link to the manual](https://www.card-tec.com/book/en_KC7.pdf).

The adapter has a cable that goes from type C to type C.

If I connect this cable directly the USB type C port in my Mac, the SD card will not show up on Finder, however if I use the `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` command I will see some information for a few seconds before the device disconnects (?).

```sh
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType
USB:
    USB 3.1 Bus:
      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8112USBXHCI

    USB 3.1 Bus:
      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8112USBXHCI

    USB 3.1 Bus:
      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8112USBXHCI

        USB Storage:

          Product ID: 0x0761
          Vendor ID: 0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.)
          Version: 24.02
          Serial Number: 000000002402
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
          Location ID: 0x00100000 / 1
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 500
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

During this nothing appears on finder, or in the system report. I'm only able to get this information by spamming the system_profiler command.

Now for the interesting bit, I have some extra adapters laying around, and if I do the following:

> Adapter -> type C to type A -> type A to type C -> MacBook

Then Finder will recognize the SD card! Calling system_profiler will result in the following:

```sh
USB:
    USB 3.1 Bus:
      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8112USBXHCI
    USB 3.1 Bus:
      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8112USBXHCI
    USB 3.1 Bus:
      Host Controller Driver: AppleT8112USBXHCI

        USB Storage:

          Product ID: 0x0751
          Vendor ID: 0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.)
          Version: 14.04
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
          Manufacturer: USB Storage
          Location ID: 0x00100000 / 1
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 98
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
          Media:
            STORAGE DEVICE:
              Capacity: 125,62 GB (125.619.404.800 bytes)
              Removable Media: Yes
              BSD Name: disk4
              Logical Unit: 0
              Partition Map Type: MBR (Master Boot Record)
              S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
              USB Interface: 0
              Volumes:
                Untitled:
                  Capacity: 125,62 GB (125.619.388.416 bytes)
                  Free: 27,49 GB (27.491.893.248 bytes)
                  Writable: Yes
                  File System: MS-DOS FAT32
                  BSD Name: disk4s1
                  Mount Point: /Volumes/Untitled
                  Content: Windows_FAT_32
```

They key thing that appears to have changed between how my computer "sees" the device is this USB storage `version` going from `24.02` to **`14.04`** and the **`MEDIA`** section being visible in the second case.

I understand there is an issue in how the USB protocol is being established, and by adding a type A connection in the path I am able to force it to be "correct".

But I have the following questions:

1. Why is this step nescessary? Is it that the adapter is cheap and does not count on this being the case?
2. Is this a classic "Apple being Apple" where the ports are designed to assume things only work in a certain way?
3. Is there any way I can fix / do something on the software level so I can use just the built-in cable and not have to create a train of adapters?

Comment: Not a solution, but indeed this should ust work. Either via USB2 (up to 480Mbit/sec) over USB-C cable, or the same Either via USB2 (up to 480Mbit/sec) over the frankstein cable.  With regards to aple being appe, I can ony offer the advise to test on other hardware and to double check connections. Which is probably obvious, but sometimes the obvious is missed.

Comment: +1 for a thoughtful question, and what might be separated out as an answer, or at least work-around -- try using a USB adapter (or hub) to allow connection. You might post that as an answer to your own question, and it would help others with that issue.

Comment: Sounds like a USB power issue. When the adapters are used, the default is to send at least 2.5W to the USB C connection. I have the same issue with a Canon scanner and my MacBook Air. Direct USB C connection is no go. But if I add a very basic USB C extension cable, the scanner magically works. FWIW, I have a [similar question posted to Ask Different (3+ years old)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/396362/40457) with no clear answer either.

Comment: Ah check, thanks for the help @Giacomo1968, interesting to see the effect is visible via power consumption as well. I wonder where something is actually going wrong, hardware, kernel or even OS.